# OnMouseMotion creates random window on top-left area with SetFocus failed

Tags: wxwidgets

I have several charts and a chart is conceptually comprised of plot area and some other elements. Part of a chart is drawn within a Plot Area and the user is able to move the plot area on a top-level window using the following code:

```
void CPlotArea::OnMouseMotion(wxMouseEvent& event)
{
        wxClientDC dc(GetParentWindow());

        wxPoint pos = event.GetLogicalPosition(dc);

        if (
            event.LeftIsDown() && 
            (event.ControlDown() || event.AltDown())
            )
        {
            wxSize distance(pos.x - m_LeftDownPos.x, pos.y - m_LeftDownPos.y);

            //dont allow too much movements (suddenly plot area gets lost)
            if (std::abs(distance.x) > 20 || std::abs(distance.y) > 20)
            {
                m_LeftDownPos = pos;

                event.Skip();
                return;
            }

            Move(distance);

            m_LeftDownPos = pos;


            GetParentWindow()->Refresh();
        }

        event.Skip();
    }
```

Please note that to move the plot area the user must click either on **Control** or **Alt** key.

And the move function is:

```
void CPlotArea::Move(const wxSize& dist)
{
        wxPoint start = m_BoundingRect.GetTopLeft();
        wxPoint End = m_BoundingRect.GetBottomRight();

        start += dist;
        End += dist;

        m_BoundingRect = wxRect(start, End);
}
```

Plot area gets the messages from another class namely ChartBase; for example for Left Down:

```
if (PlotArea && PlotArea->GetBoundingRect().Contains(pos))
{
    wxMouseEvent MouseEvent(evt);
    MouseEvent.SetAltDown(evt.AltDown());
    MouseEvent.SetControlDown(evt.ControlDown());
    MouseEvent.SetEventType(ssEVT_PLOTAREA_ONLEFTDOWN);
    wxPostEvent(PlotArea, MouseEvent);
    return;
}
```

Exactly similar rationale is followed for Motion event.

On some charts when the plot area is moved there is no problem; however, for one chart a random window appears (not sure why) on the top-left area and when clicked on it, it gives "*SetFocus failed with error 0x00000057*". It can be seen in the following image:

[image]

Appearance of the random window only happens when **Control** key is down but NOT when **Alt** key is down. Furthermore, if the user clicks the Left Button first and then the Control key, things work normal. However, if the user clicks the Control key first and then the left button down, the problem happens. Everything gets back to normal as soon as the Control key is not pressed.

The problem happens both in debug and release modes. Any ideas how to solve this problem or at least prevent the appearance of the random window?

I am using VS 2022, wxWidgets 3.1.7 on Windows 10.

Comment: what is `Move()` function doing?

Comment: Added the function to the text.

Comment: what is the difference between the one failing and the rest of them? Are you using anything external like wxShapeFramework?

Comment: I wish I had known the difference :). No, not using it.

Comment: It's impossible to say what's going on here as not enough is known about this `CPlotArea`, but one general remark: whenever you implement dragging something you _must_ capture the mouse, otherwise the behaviour will never be correct as you won't be getting some events you would normally rely on getting.

Comment: The codebase is fairly big, so I am trying to isolate as much as I can. Added some more info; hopefully that will help. I tried capturing the mouse from CPlotArea but it did not help.

Comment: @macroland, is it always the same chart? Does it depends on the position of the said chart? Cab the charts overlap each other?

Comment: Added the image of the problem and it is always the same chart causing the problem. No, regardless of the position of the plot area I still have the problem.

Comment: @macroland, do you know what kind of window is this? Can you check? I presume you create all charts the same way and you just pass different data. Another idea - can you attach a second monitor, start debugging and see at what point that window appear?

Comment: It is a frame: `class CFrmSinglePlot : public wxFrame`. The charts are specialized depending on the type of the chart, `CFrmSinglePlot` just serves as a container where things can be drawn onto. One thing with it though is, there is an event `Resized` is defined, which fires when the resizing event is done (this is just for making the charts more responsive).